# Injecting an EJB

Tags: rest, dependency-injection, ejb

I'm tryng to combine ejb and Rest in my web application. My startup bean starts with the application, gets async data from an external api and adds this data into a List, this part of application runs well.

I have to make a restful web service that returns this list.
But i'm getting always NullPointerException

Comment: You're going to have to provide us with a lot more detail. Show us some code samples, to explain what it is you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

this is my startup bean
    @startup
    @singleton
    List l=new ArrayList;
    @postConstruct
    ...initialize some manager
    ...listen to the manager
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
    ...add strings to my list
    ... getters and setters

this is my rest resource

```
@Path("nodes")
@Stateless
public class nResource {

@Context
@EJB
private nManagerLocal nManagerLocal;


@GET
@Produces({MediaType.TEXT_XML})
public List<Node> getIds() {
  List<Node> l=nManagerLocal.getNodes();

  return l;
}
```

i wasn't able to get the bean instance in my resource.. i forgot to insert @stateless annotation :) Problem resolved..

now i'm tryng to inject my bean also in a Managed bean